# How can i get all work items across all Team Services accounts?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, object-model, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the .NET libraries for accessing Visual Studio Team Services and i'm trying to work around a glaring design flaw on Microsoft's part. Apparently you can't have more than one collection per server/account, so i have to use several accounts, which in this example i'll refer to as collections, since Microsoft has even made clear [they map to the same thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/how-we-plan-to-enable-creating-multiple-collections-per-account/).

What i'm actually trying to achieve is to have a list with all my work items from all the collections i'm a member of. I have a QueryWorkItems() method that uses GetAllCollections() to get all my collections. That method has been tested and it works, it does return the two accounts i have. The top level method that triggers the whole thing is AssignedWorkItems(). My code is as follows:

```
        public static List<TfsTeamProjectCollection> GetAllCollections()
        {
            // Get collections/accounts associated with user
            string request = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Accounts?memberId=" + versionControl.AuthorizedIdentity.TeamFoundationId + "&api-version=3.2-preview";
            string content = MakeRequestToAPI(request).Result;
            dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
            List<TfsTeamProjectCollection> collections = new List<TfsTeamProjectCollection>();
            // Iterate through all collections
            Parallel.ForEach((IEnumerable<dynamic>)results.value, collection =>
           {
               TfsTeamProjectCollection col = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri((string)collection.accountUri));
               collections.Add(col);
           });
            return collections;
        }


        public static List<WorkItem> QueryWorkItems(string query)
        {
            List<WorkItem> workItems = new List<WorkItem>();
            List<TfsTeamProjectCollection> collections = GetAllCollections();
            //Parallel.ForEach(collections, collection =>
            foreach(var collection in collections)
            {
                WorkItemCollection items = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>().Query(query);
                // Add each work item to the overall list
                Parallel.For(0, items.Count, i =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(items[i].Title);
                    lock (workItems)
                    {
                        workItems.Add(items[i]);
                    }
                });
            }

            return workItems;
        }

        public static List<WorkItem> AssignedWorkItems()
        {
            Init(); //initializes variables like projectName, workItemStore and VersionControlServer(versionControl)
            string myItems = "select * from issue where [System.AssignedTo]=@me";
            return QueryWorkItems(myItems);
        }
```

When i call the AssignedWorkItems method i get a login prompt, even though i have a default connection already setup:[image]

After i input my credentials though, in this line:

> WorkItemCollection items = collection.GetService().Query(query);

i get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team
>   Foundation Server: https://xxxxxx.vssps.visualstudio.com/.
>
> Team Foundation Server Url: https://xxxxxx.vssps.visualstudio.com/
>
> Possible reasons for failure include:
>
> - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
> - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
> - The password has expired or is incorrect.

Funny thing is everytime i run this the URL mentioned in the error switches back and forth between the two collections i have. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can test the method **`QueryWorkItems`** successfully.

Based on the error message you got, it seems the VSTS URL stored in `collections` as the format https://account.vssps.visualstudio.com instead of https://account.visualstudio.com. So please confirm the URLs stored in collections for the method **`GetAllCollections`** are correct.

I used this **`GetAllCollections`** method to verify **`QueryWorkItems`**:

```
public static List<TfsTeamProjectCollection> GetAllCollections()
{

    List<TfsTeamProjectCollection> collections = new List<TfsTeamProjectCollection>();

    NetworkCredential cred1 = new NetworkCredential("username for Alternate authentication", "password for Alternate authentication");
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc1 = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://account1.visualstudio.com"), cred1);

    collections.Add(tpc1);

    NetworkCredential cred2 = new NetworkCredential("username for Alternate authentication", "password for Alternate authentication");
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc2 = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://account2.visualstudio.com"), cred2);

    collections.Add(tpc2);
    return collections;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to be the issue. Do i really need to set credentials, though? It presents me with the login prompt if i'm not logged in and if i am it just gives me the results i want anyway. 

If i do need to set credentials, can't i just have the same set of credentials for all collections? I'm a member in all of them, afterall.

Comment: It's not necessary, it only save you not input your credentials when the code executing. You can also use  `TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://account.visualstudio.com"))` instead.